# PostgreSQL 9.6 version server unintentionally upgraded to version 14.5, now database cannot start, what to do?

Tags: postgresql

This is not a production system but it happened on my development laptop. I have PostgreSQL running on cygwin basis on a Windows 10 platform. The other day I was going to just add some other cygwin binary, but while doing so, the entire software suite was updated to the latest versions of everything. Now my postgresql system runs at version 14.5.

My dilemma is this: I could just cut my losses and throw away the database cluster and start over from scratch. But I might spend 2 or 3 days to recover from all the things that I would need to have back. A lot of work I am not even sure what would have been lost.

Size of the database on disk is about 8 GB. A bit heavy to move to some Unix system in the cloud to try and mount it from there pull a backup, and replay it all.

Is there any tool that I could use to just read the raw tuples to just look around and possibly recover some bigger tables that are worth not rebuilding from scratch?

Comment: Whatever else you do, I would advise to start with a file-level backup of your database directory. Then consider the useful answers given.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's hard to tell what happened. I have no idea what cygwin does. I have no idea how Postgres is *started* in cygwin. Whatever you use maybe tries to start 14, but some (unknown) configuration file points to the data directory of 9.6.

Something like the following should work.

Find out which configuration file in cygwin configures/controls how Postgres is started and what it thinks where the data directory is located. Then change this to make it start 9.6 with the (hopefully still existing) 9.6 data directory. Make a backup of the database  (`pg_dumpall --globals-only` to dump the user definitions, `pg_dump` to backup the data).

Then properly initialize a (new) data directory for 14 using its initdb binaries. Change those configuration files again to start the 14 binaries with the newly created data directory and then restore the dumps taken in the previous step.

While you are at it, it might be better to dump the cygwin solution and use the native Windows binaries instead.

Comment: To install again I would have to first build it from source from some old archive. I tried to find 9.x binaries but there is no archive on the cygwin binaries. And starting Windows binaries would not go anywhere. 

Comment: @GuntherSchadow: what's wrong with the Windows binaries provided by EDB?

Comment: I did pg_ctl start and it did something and then just stopped. Like these crashes that don't generate any information.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the new software was installed, but the server was not upgraded; look into the PostgreSQL log to be certain. You have to install PostgreSQL 9.6 again, perhaps from source, start the 9.6 server on the existing data directory and `pg_dumpall` the cluster. Run `initdb` from v14 to create a new cluster, start the server and import the dump. Then you have upgraded the database and can get rid of the old data directory and the old software.

Comment: To install again I would have to first build it from source from some old archive. I tried to find 9.x binaries but there is no archive on the cygwin binaries. And starting Windows binaries would not go anywhere. 

Comment: Yes, it is not trivial.